# AIS Sentence Sequential Message ID Usage

Tags: nmea, ais

[Here](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/AIVDM.html#_aivdm_aivdo_sentence_layer) explained that the field 4 is a sequential message ID for multi-sentence messages. What does it means? What is the difference between field 4 and field 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the website:

> Field 2 (1 in this example) is the **count of fragments** in the currently accumulating message. The payload size of each sentence is limited by NMEA 0183’s 82-character maximum, so it is sometimes required to split a payload over several fragment sentences.
>
> Field 3 (1 in this example) is the **fragment number** of this sentence. It will be one-based. A sentence with a fragment count of 1 and a fragment number of 1 is complete in itself.
>
> Field 4 (empty in this example) is a sequential **message ID** for multi-sentence messages.

Consider a message sent using 2 fragments:

- Field 2 will be `2`, the number of fragments.
- Field 3 will be `1` for the first fragment, and `2` for the second
- Field 4 can be any digit between `0` and `9`, but will be common for both messages. This number is incremented for each new multi-fragment message sent by a vessel. It allows the decoding program to match together fragments that belong to the same message.

Here's one other example:

```
!AIVDM,2,1,8,A,56;OaD02B8EL990b221`P4v1T4pN0HDpN2222216HHN>B6U30A2hCDhD`888,0*4D
!AIVDM,2,2,8,A,88888888880,2*2C
```

The message has `2` parts (from field #2), we can see fragments `1` and `2` (from field #3), and the message_id for both fragments of this message is `8` (from field #4).

From the same vessels, I had previously received message ID `7`, and right before this message ID `6`, etc.

Comment: Clear answer. Do you ever found message id (field 4) value of more than 10?

Comment: From a quick lookup in a large amount of AIS antenna logs, I've seen all numbers between 0 and 9 includes, but never more.

Comment: I have observed that the sequence number does not appear to be incremented by the sending transponder (vessel) alone but is incremented for any vessel i.e. vessel A: seq 0, vessel B: seg 1, vessel C: seq 2, vessel B: seq 3, vessel C: seq 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's to late for answer this now, but it could help others...
This field 4, the sequential message id, runs from 0 to 9 and then start over 0. It's incremented each time a new multi-sentence message is generated, this is why the vessel A is seq 0, vessel B seq 1, etc because the receiver creates the NMEA messages and each multi-sentence message outputted increases this number no matter the transmitter (the Vessel)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).